# Check to see if cronjobs are executed

Tags: linux, email, cron

I am running a cronjob every 15 minutes, and I want to be notified (preferably by email) whenever the job is NOT being run. That is, if cron is not running the job at all.

I am aware that I can check log files manually, but I want this to be an automated check every time cron is supposed to execute a command.

Does cron provide any ways of doing this, or do I need something else?

Comment: What do you mean by "not executing"? That it doesn't run at all or that it crashes and never finishes? For it to not run at all it would seem CRON would have to be too broken to send email too...?

Comment: Sorry if the question was unclear. What you are describing is exactly what my problem is. What I mean by "not executing" is that it doesn't run at all. So, how can I automate this task if CRON itself is causing the job to not run.

Comment: I cannot see any way, if you assume that `crond` was not started or has crashed. Who or what will send you the email?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use second machine for that if you want to have really robust solution. Your first machine would need to put a time of last execution somewhere (post on the web site or some other shared resources), and then second machine would need to check that time periodically and if it differ from current - shoot email to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a cron to send a mail confirming an execution of the job. add following line before job line in crobtab file

```
MAILTO='Yourmail@domain.com'
#Cron entry goes here.


MAILTO='Yourmail@domain.com'
#second cron entry goes here.
```

Then make your job print/echo something on each execution(at start itself). like a simple statement 'A job started'. On the job execution this output will be mailed to given mail id. If you receive the mail cron is executed, if not something is wrong, give it a check.

Comment: This way you will receive emails every so often as job is executed. And I think the main point was to receive email much less often, when something goes wrong.